# menu alignment- wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have a problem with one menu item that appears to be left-aligned rather than centered as the rest of the menu items.
[link to site](https://expert-bc.com/)

You can see that there is a smaller space between the first and second menu items. (site is RTL so first from the right)
Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet contains the following:

```
.fl-page-nav-left .fl-page-nav ul.navbar-nav>li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

You can find this in your stylesheet and remove it.

Alternatively, you can add the following CSS:

```
.fl-page-nav-left .fl-page-nav ul.navbar-nav>li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 25px !important;
}
```

Comment: every time i removed the above code from the stylesheet, it automaticly created another one with the same code.

Comment: @dormeljon That sounds strange... but it's working now?

Answer (score 0):

Your first menu item (from the right) has been styled with the following CSS:

```
.fl-page-nav-left .fl-page-nav ul.navbar-nav > li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

This piece of css is used for a styling in a non-RTL website; the padding is on the left side of the menu item. Change it to:

```
.fl-page-nav-left .fl-page-nav ul.navbar-nav > li:first-child a {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```